# Asp.Net Core 3 how to put a function in the program.cs file - The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, function, asp.net-core, config, startup

The November 2021 release of AspNet Core 3 has a Program.cs file without any methods, you simply configure the services.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```

However, if you need to add a method, eg:

```
public Task OnFallbackAsync(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> response, Context context)
{
    Console.WriteLine("About to call the fallback action. This is a good place to do some logging");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

You get an error:

> The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item

How to declare functions in the Program.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the scope keyword (Private, Internal, Public):

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
    
Task OnFallbackAsync(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> response, Context context)
{
    Console.WriteLine("About to call the fallback action. This is a good place to do some logging");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: This is basically a local function, you should probably mention that.

Comment: Also, this is a "feature" of top-level statements in C#, it's not specific to the new ASP.NET Core templates.

Comment: You can also create the project as .NET 5 and later switch to .NET 6. This way you are not using the new templates.